# Interpretation of songsterr tab

Tags: fingering, tablature, fingerstyle-guitar, harmonics

Hi guys I'm looking at a tab on songsterr (Use Somebody fingerstyle) and at the 8th bar the tab indicates the playing of the open CGC strings and above it says t.h.(12) and t.h.(19).
Can anyone explain what this means?
I also need help from the 96th to the 105th bar where it requires playing on the 2nd and 6th fret. Is there any advice on how to position my fingers/what chord/technique to play this bit?

I'm relatively new to the guitar and i can get the harmonics and the rest of the song down but im having trouble with the above. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: T.H. = tapped harmonics.

Comment: “open CGC strings” - open tuning? Link to what you are looking at?

Comment: @b3ko It uses CGCGCe tuning: https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/kings-of-leon-use-somebody-fingerstyle-tab-s88415t0

Comment: An image would be worth a thousand words here in terms of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

T.H mean tapped harmonic.
t.h.(19) = use your right hand finger to tap on 19th fret.